# retrieve style options from tkinter widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, styles

I'm trying to make a function that lists all the style options of the clicked widget.

For this I created two buttons, one with the default Tbutton style, and another with the modified test.Tbutton style that has a red foreground.

But when it comes time to list the values of the options, the modification of foreground to red does not appear...

has a 'text' option also with no defined value. Shouldn't it have the button text???

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


top = Tk()
top.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: top.destroy())


def show_options(e):
    wg = e.widget
    if wg['style']:
        classe = wg['style']
    else:
        classe = wg.winfo_class()
        
    print(classe)
    layout = s.layout(classe)

    btnborder = layout[0][1]
    btn_style = s.element_options('Button.border')

    btnfocus = btnborder['children'][0][1]
    btn_style += s.element_options('Button.focus')
          
    btnpadding = btnfocus['children'][0][1]
    btn_style += s.element_options('Button.padding')

    btnlabel = btnpadding['children'][0][1]
    btn_style += s.element_options('Button.label')

    btn_style = sorted(set(btn_style))

    for o in btn_style:
        print(o, s.lookup('TButton', o))

    print('\n')


s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('teste.TButton', foreground='red')

b = ttk.Button(top, text='foo')
b.bind('<1>', show_options)
b.pack()

b1 = ttk.Button(top, text='ni', style='teste.TButton')
b1.bind('<1>', show_options)
b1.pack()
```

Comment: I don't understand which button to turn red.  for o in btn_style:
        print(o, s.lookup('TButton', o))
        s.configure('TButton', foreground='red')

    print('\n')

Comment: yes... I was passing the element name to lookup() instead of the style name. Apparently layout() only serves to retrieve the available options. I thought I could individually change layout elements like Button.label, or Button.padding.
```
def show_options(classe, elementos):
    for e in elementos:
        print('\n', e)
        for o in s.element_options(e):
            print(o, s.lookup(classe, o))
```